# Coding style: How to name the props to understand which props are from a parent or redux clearly?

Tags: reactjs, redux, coding-style, react-props

When I accept redux props and parent props in a component, I notice that it is really hard to recognize the props by name which is from parent or redux.

for example

The component below accepts four variables: `isOpenSidebar`, `toogleSidebar`, `isOpenMenu`, and `toogleMenu`. However `isOpenSidebar`, `toogleSidebar` are from redux, and `isOpenMenu`, `toogleMenu` are from parent props.

To call the props' name from different origins, I consider using underline after the variable to mark the props from redux like this `isOpenSidebar_`, or adding a prefix before the props like this `redux_isOpenSidebar` or `rdx_isOpenSidebar.` But I am not sure if these are good ideas?

Is there any good and standard method to name the props from different origins?

```
const Header = ({ isOpenSidebar, toogleSidebar, isOpenMenu, toogleMenu }) => {
  return (
    <header>
      {!isOpenSidebar && (
        <div onClick={() => toogleSidebar(true)}>
          open sidebar
        </div>
      )}

      {!isOpenMenu && (
        <div onClick={() => toogleMenu(!isOpenMenu)}>
          open menu
        </div>
      )}

      <h4>header</h4>
    </header>
  );
};

export default connect(
  (state) => ({
    isOpenSidebar: state.ui.isOpenSidebar,
  }),
  { toogleSidebar }
)(Header);
```

Comment: Component shouldn't know where props came from. If it does, something wrong in your architecture

Comment: I am facing this same problem. Seems that a component that is being loaded for the first time, first recieves props from parent components and then redux props. To handle this initial load you might need to handle this specific case where you need to tell the component "ignore pros passed from parent for this first time in the initial load". Wonder what woul be the way to handle this throught the arquitechture instead of distinguishing where the props are coming from

Comment: Thank you both for your comments. 
I know that a component shouldn't know where the props come from. I am just wondering whether I can leave hints in the naming convention for others and myself to tell the different origins of the props so that it will be easier for us to maintain them in the future.